# Error trying to map an list of Maps in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
main() {
  var alunos = [
    {"nome": "Alfreado", "nota": 9.3},
    {"nome": "Joao", "nota": 6.8},
    {"nome": "Mariana", "nota": 8.4},
    {"nome": "Joana", "nota": 8.9},
    {"nome": "Gustavo", "nota": 7.3},
    {"nome": "Ana", "nota": 9.1},
  ];
  
}

String Function(Map) pegarApenasONome = (aluno) => aluno["nome"];

var nomes = alunos.map(pegarApenasONome);
```

Guys, im trying to map the list `alunos`, but when i try, it shows an red line saying and i quote:

"Undefined name 'alunos'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name."

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you created `alunos` in `main()` but trying to use it global. You need to make all of them local or global

```
main() {
  var alunos = [
    {"nome": "Alfreado", "nota": 9.3},
    {"nome": "Joao", "nota": 6.8},
    {"nome": "Mariana", "nota": 8.4},
    {"nome": "Joana", "nota": 8.9},
    {"nome": "Gustavo", "nota": 7.3},
    {"nome": "Ana", "nota": 9.1},
  ];

String Function(Map) pegarApenasONome = (aluno) => aluno["nome"];

var nomes = alunos.map(pegarApenasONome);  
}
```

Comment: @DennisCastro Mark as correct answer if it is correct